# How to get CaptureDevices using JMF Package in Java?

Tags: java, audio, capture, jmf

I just start to use JMF package in java and when I used to get the capture devices of my computer, it returns null for me. I don't know what is the reason and if my code is wrong!

Sorry if my question is very simple but I need the answer soon, so I asked it.

Below is the code:

```
 CaptureDeviceInfo di = new CaptureDeviceInfo();
 Vector deviceList = CaptureDeviceManager.getDeviceList(null); 
 if (deviceList.size() > 0)
         di = (CaptureDeviceInfo)deviceList.firstElement();
 else
     System.out.println("Not get");
```